# Invoke functions dynamically in a chain

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to invoke functions dynamically in a chain. I am able to get this working with a reference to class and function name but I am trying to make it more dynamic. Any thoughts, please?

*testFunctions.py*

```
class TestFunctions(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def test1(self, **param1):
        print('inside test1() with args:'+str(param1))
        return param1.get('param1'), 'xyz'

    def test2(self, param1, param2):
        print('inside test2() with args:'+param1+','+param2)
        return 'test2'


    def test3(self, param1):
        print('inside test3() with args:'+param1)
        return "Hello"
```

Test code that works:

```
from testFunctions import TestFunctions

param1 = {}
param1['param1'] = 'ABCD'
tClass = TestFunctions()
output = tClass.test3(tClass.test2(*tClass.test1(**param1)))
print(output)
```

Test code to make it dynamic that works similar to above test:

```
from testFunctions import TestFunctions
param1 = {}
param1['param1'] = 'ABCD'
tClass = TestFunctions()
funcList = ['test3', 'test2', 'test1']
for funcName in funcList:
    func = getattr(tClass, funcName)
    func()
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I wanted to invoke test3, test2 and test1 functions where they are defined as a string. Each of these methods take parameters that are passed in from other functions. Under tests that works, I have defined the order and the parameters the functions take.

Comment: In your first example you change the way the function is called each time. This is going to be hard to generalize unless the return from one function matches the signature of the next and you can call them all the same way. Can you change the functions?

Comment: What is the question? "Any thoughts please?" seems to be an open-ended request for feedback rather than a specific inquiry.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I can change the functions to return dict and update the functions to take **kwargs if that can solve the problem. Any other suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have some flexibility in the functions, you can tweak them so they all have the same signature. It doesn't really matter what it is, but if you can all them all the same way and the previous function delivers the expected argument of the next function everything will be easier.

For example, where I've changed the functions so they are all called with a single argument — that could be a tuple, dictionary, or single scaler. With that it's trivial to put in a loop or `reduce()`:

```
class TestFunctions(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def test1(self, param): # expects a mapping
        print('inside test1() with args:'+str(param))
        return param1.get('param1'), 'xyz'

    def test2(self, params): # expects a sequence
        print('inside test2() with args:'+params[0]+','+params[1])
        return 'test2'

    def test3(self, param): # scalar value
        print('inside test3() with args:'+param)
        return "Hello"

from functools import reduce

tClass = TestFunctions()
funcList = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
val = {'param1': 'ABCD'}

for f in funcList:
    val =  getattr(tClass, f)(val)
print(val)
```

**Result:**

```
inside test1() with args:{'param1': 'ABCD'}
inside test2() with args:ABCD,xyz
inside test3() with args:test2
Hello
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will update the functions to use single param